# customize edit popup of command in the grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

have a simple kendo grid, with edit and destroy command.

the edit command, shows a popup, where i can modify my data.
I need to customize the title, and the buttons texts (update and cancel button) of the edit window.
this is my code:

```
var ds = createJSONDataSource();

function createJSONDataSource() {

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

    transport: {
        autoSync: true,
        read: {
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebServices/GetDataTest.asmx/getCustList",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: mime_charset
        }
    },
    pageSize: 5,
    schema: {
        data: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                if (serverSelectReturnsJSONString)
                    return $.parseJSON(data.d);

                else
                    return data.d;
            }
        },
        model:{
              id: "customer_id",
              fields: {
              customer_id: { type: "string", editable: false },
              name_customer: { type: "string" },
              address_customer: { type: "string" }
               }
         }
   });

    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    selectable: true,
    theme: "metro",
    dataSource: ds,
    scrollable: {
        virtual: true
    },
    reorderable: true,
    resizable: true,
    pageable: true,
    height: 300,
    toolbar: ["save", "cancel"],
    columns: [
        { field: "customer_id", title: "ID" },
        { field: "name_customer", title: "Cliente" },
        { field: "address_customer", title: "Indirizzo" },
        { field: "PI_customer", title: "Partita IVA", hidden: true },
        { field: "cap_customer", title: "CAP", hidden: true },
        { field: "city_customer", title: "Città" },
        { field: "state_customer", title: "Nazione", selected: false },
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;" }
    ],
    filterable: true,
    editable: "popup",
    sortable: true,
    columnMenu: {
        messages: {
            columns: "Scegli colonne",
            filter: "Applica filtro",
            sortAscending: "Ordina (ASC)",
            sortDescending: "Ordina (DESC)"
        }

    },
    groupable: {
        messages: {
            empty: "Trascina la colonna qui..."
        }
    }

});
```

Hope someone helps me!

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For customizing the buttons you should define command as:

```
{
    name: "edit",
    text: { update: "Actualizar", cancel: "Cancelar"}
},
```

Where I replaced `Update` by `Actualizar` and `Cancel` by `Cancelar`.

So your columns definition would be:

```
columns: [
    { field: "customer_id", title: "ID" },
    { field: "name_customer", title: "Cliente" },
    { field: "address_customer", title: "Indirizzo" },
    { field: "PI_customer", title: "Partita IVA", hidden: true },
    { field: "cap_customer", title: "CAP", hidden: true },
    { field: "city_customer", title: "Città" },
    { field: "state_customer", title: "Nazione", selected: false },
    { 
        command: [
            {
                name: "edit",
                text: { update: "Actualizar", cancel: "Cancelar"}
            }, 
            "destroy"
        ], 
        title: "&nbsp;"
    }
],
```

For changing the title of the window, you should change the `editable: "popup",` by:

```
editable  : {
    mode : "popup",
    window : {
        title: "Edición",
    }
},
```

Where I define the title as `Edición`.

Answer (score 0):

Credit for this actually belongs to     Adarsh K      answered Jun 10 '14 at 15:00
But I believe I read that you should not post links to other answers so, please if Mr OnaBai would stop answering these posts and ignoring the fact that everyone is doing a POPUP NOT the on-grid command buttons we all could be much happier... and now Mr. Adarsh K's elegant answer & my addition  ..

```
function OnEdit(e){
if (e.model.isNew())
 {
  var update = $(e.container).parent().find(".k-grid-update");
  $(update).html('<span class="k-icon k-update"></span>Insert');
  }
 }
```

This is a "section" in the .kendoGrid  umm 'structure', this inline function additionally allows you to change the title of the ***POPUP*** dialog box conditionally ...  Here my Add section (is new) changes the button text to save and the title to my edit ***POPUP*** to the Add text title instead of the Edit text title...

```
        edit: function (e)
        {
            if (e.model.isNew())
            {
                $('.k-window-title').text("Add New xxxxxxxxxx");
                var update = $(e.container).parent().find(".k-grid-update");
                $(update).html('<span class="k-icon k-update"></span>Save');
            }                           
            else
            { $('.k-window-title').text("Edit Existing xxxxxxxxxxx"); }
        },

        columns: [
                        { field:.........
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to customize is as following:

```
columns: [
{ command: 
    [{ name: 'edit', 
    click: editButtonClick, 
    template: editButtonTemplate }], title: 'Edit', width: '40px'}..]


var editButtonTemplate = '<a class="btn btn-link btn-xs k-grid-edit" href="\\#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>';

editButtonClick = function (e) {
/* Changes default rendering of 'update' & 'cancel' buttons
 * but keeps default behaviour
 */
var btnCancel = $('.k-grid-cancel');
btnCancel.removeClass('k-button k-button-icontext').addClass('btn btn-link btn-xs');
btnCancel.text('');
btnCancel.append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span>');

var btnOk = $('.k-grid-update');
btnOk.removeClass('k-button k-button-icontext k-primary').addClass('btn btn-link btn-xs');
btnOk.text('');
btnOk.append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle k-update"></span>');
```

}

This approach handles `click` event of standard `edit` command and modifies rendered html, but preserves standard functionality.

*Important detail* - grid's update functionality is coupled to element with `k-update` attribute, while cancel functionality rides on `k-grid-cancel`.